# How to get all data from Epic via API?

Tags: versionone

To get data of Epic, I fired below API query:

```
http://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic
```

But it is giving only default column. I need all data from Epic including fields, Relations etc. I can see all fields of Epic from below

```
http://YourVersionOneInstance/VersionOne/meta.v1?xsl=api.xsl#Epic
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a dump of all attibutes might get you less than optimal performance. The rest api is optimized to be used for specific queries. When querying the rest api, the default response data contains the most useful subset of attributes and relations for most users. To get more than the default attributes, you will have to list each and every one of them as select arguments.

i.e.  `http://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Name,ID, ....`